# .jsundefined .cssundefined webpack chunks on page refresh using Next JS

Tags: webpack, static, next.js

In this question, more than searching for a solution, I hope you could guide me into the right direction.

I'm using Next JS.

My problem occurs in production, reaching a page like `pages/product.tsx` works OK the first time. Capture 2 shows that the html script links are correctly formed.

But, refreshing that same page produce all the css or js extensions turn into `.jsundefined` or `.cssundefined`.

The project is deployed on my own *digitalocean* server.
When I deploy that same project to Vercel (best way of deploying Next JS projects), it solves the issue.

Please guide me into what could probably be causing this.

**next.config.js**

```js
const withCss = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
});

module.exports = withCss(
  withMDX({
    pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "md", "mdx"],
  })
);
```

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[capture 1: chunks with jsundefined cssundefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZS0Q.png)

[capture 2: normal chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImBU5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporal solution.
My project was on the latest Next JS version (9.5), which implements Incremental Static Generation. That was causing problems.
I just needed to downgrade to Next JS 9.4 and now the issue is solved but I still dont understand why.

**Edit: AUG/12/2020**

Ok, I finally discover the real issue.
I was doing something like this in my urls:

```js
import Link from "next/link"

...
<Link href="product/[productId]" as={`product/${id}`} passHref >
    <a href={`product/${id}`}>
        ...
    </a>
</Link>
...
```

or worst

```js
...
<Link href={`product/${id}`} passHref>
    <a href={`product/${id}`}>
        ...
    </a>
</Link>
...
```

I read the docs again and now I do this

```js
import Link from "next/link"

...
<Link href="/product/[productId]" as={`/product/${id}`}>
    <a>
        ...
    </a>
</Link>
...
```

Now I can safely install the latest version of Next JS (9.5) without problems.

Comment: Sorry for a two-year late comment, but I am wondering do you know more details about this problem? I have encountered the same issue, but I didn't use the Link component in my app. I also want to know how the Link component is related to webpack output.